# lighttpd URL Redirect - subdirectory to root

Tags: lighttpd, redirect

I have a lighttpd setup with a structure along the lines of

```
/var/www
/var//www/php
/var/www/icons
```

Icons used to be a folder inside the php folder but I moved it to make the job of synchronizing folder contents easier - since the icons folder contents do not change very often.  However, this has left me with a legacy of references in CSS markup and JavaScript code that seek out images at /var/www/php/icons.  I have played around with url.redirect

```
url.redirect = ("/var/www/php/icons" => "/var/www/icons")
```

but as far as I can see that does nothing at all.  When I visit the offending page in my browser I still get an HTTP 404 being reported for /var/www/php/icons.

I imagine I am missing something or am writing the redirect rule incorrectly but I have not been able to figure out something that actually works.  I'd much appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your redirects for complete paths, not just directories. In your case, it would be:

```
url.redirect = ("/var/www/php/icons/(.*)" => "/var/www/icons/$1")
```

This regex will match complete paths and catch the filename in the group which we can then place into the redirect using the `$1`.

*Disclaimer: I didn't test this, maybe my syntax is bad, but matching the complete path is necessary.

Comment: Thanks! - and sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.